# Input fields like textbox, select are not cleared on submit

Tags: angularjs-ng-model

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('nameController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  alert("controller called");
   $scope.addNewName = function() 
   {
    $scope.showSection = true;
  };

  $scope.submit = function() {
    alert("Added");
    $scope.adduserform.aname = "";
    $scope.showSection = false;
  }

}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div layout="row" ng-controller="nameController">
  <div>
    <md-button aria-label="add" type="button" class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="addNewName()">Add New Name</md-button>
  </div>

  <!-- below section will be shown when on click on Add New Name button -->
  <form ng-show="showSection" name="adduserform">
    <label>Enter Name: </label>
    <md-input-container>
      <input type="text" ng-model="adduserform.aname" aria-label="name" id="aname" required/>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button type="button" aria-label="submit"  class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="submit()">Submit</md-button>
  </form>
</div>
  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
 
  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
   
  
   
</body>
</html>
```

Input fields like textbox, select are not cleared on submit. The fields are referred by `ng-model` and used as `$scope.modelname` in the code. After I click on submit - i clear them with `$scope.modelname=''`.
When I open the form again without refreshing the page - the fields are highlighted in red.
Assume the form is like Add User form. When I click on submit for 1st user and reopen the form again to add another user. When i reopen the form - it gets the field highlighted. I know its because the field is mentioned as required and hence it makes this error. How should I clear them and also make sure the field is not highlighted when i reopen the form? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving $scope.modelname={};
Or else you can try this way,scope.$$nextSibling.modelname = '';

Let me know,if this helped or not

Comment: No it doesnt work. {} is setting [Object Object] to the field and nextSibling - behaves same as the issue. It clears the value but fidl is highlighted in when the form is reopened

Comment: If possible can u run your code in jsfiddle or plunker and give that link here..It will be easy to help

Comment: I am new to this Fiddle.. Pls forgive. I have added a sample code to the original post. Please let me know

Comment: Np...In the above i see validation is not working properly.u are able to submit even though no name is submiitted

Comment: Put that text field in a form ..Then validation will work fine